# hr in contenteditable div accepts text

Tags: html, css

If we do have a `contenteditable` `div`, and an `hr` inside it, then the `hr` can be clicked on and text can be written "inside it".

See it in action in this code block:

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  Hello
  <hr contenteditable="false">
  There
  
  <br><br>
  <button contenteditable="false">Cannot edit this</button>
</div>
```

Can we disable the HR being editable in an editable div?

[image: Cursor in an uncomfortable position]

Note: You have to click on the exact HR line.
I added the button to show that contenteditable doesn't affect it if its own contenteditable is set to false.

Comment: hr tags don't have a closing tag. Nothing is being written "inside" the hr tag. Clicking on the hr tag simply place the cursor inside the div. Personally I like using the XHTML model which has hr, br, etc. self closing: <br />, <hr />, etc.

Comment: Still it looks very wrong to have the cursor right below the HR and through the text (see image). I tried using line-height but didn't help.

Comment: Yes, William_Wilson is right - but HR in contenteditable is pretty unaccountable and gives rise to odd cursor positioning as you've found. I prefer to use border-bottom styles with padding / margin

Comment: @TonyDuffill can you suggest html/css of an element that has a line and 
is unclickable/uneditable?

Comment: Not really - the trick I use is with javascript - when the HR element is clicked it is highlighted by outlining but loses focus. That way, it can't receive keystrokes but you can still add classes or styles to the selected HR.  Tony